# File opener multiple path

Tags: 20.04, firefox, chromium, upload

I'd like to upload multiple files, from different locations at once, can I do it somehow?

When i select the file, what I want to upload, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, and tried to add some paths like: `/xy/ab/file`, `xyz/jk/file`, but didn't work.

Comment: Not clear.  Your tags suggest you use Firefox Chromium, but these are normally used for downloading not uploading (except with some ftp add on).

Comment: For example: jpg to pdf converter, or upload images to a gallery, etc.

Comment: Understood.  You upload files to some web page and would like to use full path.

Comment: I am trying with Firefox on Facebook for example and the Control L thing works: I can input full path like `/home/user/Desktop/xxx.jpg`.  But this is not a question on Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried this on windows, and it worked, but not on Ubuntu, thats why I asked here :) 

Yes, that works, with only one file, but what am i asking is what to do, when i want to upload multiple files, with different path.

Comment: Maybe you do not type correctly the path.  After Control L. type / and you should see an autocompletion menu. You could generate the filelist, save it to a text file, then copy paste to web browser but complex uploads are usually performed by ftp (for example FileZilla).

Comment: And what should be the 'separator'?

Comment: The separator is /.  If drag and drop works you can also open a Nautilus window for each location, drag from Nautilus windows and drop to web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select the files through the system file dialog, which in current Ubuntu versions is provided by the GTK3 toolkit. Unfortunately, you are seeing a limitation in that dialog. While it is possible to specify different files - however only within the same folder - by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then clicking files to select them, you can specify only a single file at a time using the path bar that you obtain after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. There is not any possibility to specify files from different directories.

A workaround would be to link (hard or symbolic) the different files in different folders in a single folder (or just copy the files) so you can upload them in a single move.

You can enable options for creating a symbolic link in the "Preferences" of Files, on the "Behavior" tab.